# Do Scala types really form a lattice?

Tags: scala, algebra

There seems to be a somewhat widespread conception that Scala types form a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)).

I can get three quarters of the way there, and define a [semilattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice) by defining *top* = `Any`, *bottom* = `Nothing`, and *meet* = `with`. Then *≤* is at least mostly equivalent to`<:`, ie the subtyping relation.

Scala is even kind enough to help us test at least some of the lattice laws:

```
scala> implicitly[Nothing =:= Nothing]
res0: =:=[Nothing,Nothing] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[Nothing =:= String with Nothing]
res1: =:=[Nothing,String with Nothing] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[Nothing =:= String with Any]
<console>:11: error: Cannot prove that Nothing =:= String with Any.
       implicitly[Nothing =:= String with Any]
                 ^

scala> implicitly[Any =:= String with Any]
<console>:11: error: Cannot prove that Any =:= String with Any.
       implicitly[Any =:= String with Any]
                 ^

scala> implicitly[Any =:= Any]
res4: =:=[Any,Any] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[Any =:= Any with String]
<console>:11: error: Cannot prove that Any =:= Any with String.
       implicitly[Any =:= Any with String]
                 ^

scala> implicitly[String =:= Any with String]
res6: =:=[String,Any with String] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[String =:= String with Any]
res7: =:=[String,String with Any] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[String =:= (String with Any)]
res8: =:=[String,String with Any] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[Int with String =:= String with Int]
res9: =:=[Int with String,String with Int] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[Boolean with (Int with String) =:= (Boolean with Int) with (Boolean with String)]                            
res11: =:=[Boolean with Int with String,Boolean with Int with Boolean with String] = <function1>
```

So, now all that is missing is a suitable definition of *join*. Is there an equivalent to *join* in Scala?

You need not use my above definitions for *top*, *bottom*, and *meet*, but it is preferred as this is more than just a theoretical question. I actually want to use the join of two types. As a workaround for now, since I don't know how to write `A` *join* `B`, I'll define a new `trait` with abstract methods for the methods in both `A` and `B`, and modify `A` and `B` to inherit from it.

Comment: I don't think so. You might be able to define a lattice using this [brilliant hack from miles sabin](http://milessabin.com/blog/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/), but for a straightforward usage you would have to wait for [dotty](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty)